# Any easy way to transform 1-1 to Jan 1 in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime, transform

I have a column of str-like dates as follows:
1-1
1-2
1-3
...
1-31
2-1
...
12-31
Any easy way to transform it to
Jan 1
Jan 2
...
Dec 31
I want to plot the transformed dates to matplotlib x-axis.
I am a beginner on python and pandas. I looked for some methods such as strftime and to_datetime but didn't find out solutions.Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': '1-1 1-2 1-3 1-31 2-1'.split()})

df['col'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col'], format='%m-%d').dt.strftime('%b %d')
print (df)

      col
0  Jan 01
1  Jan 02
2  Jan 03
3  Jan 31
4  Feb 01
```